# SQL: asign array return value as a tuple

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, destructuring

Let's say I have a value like `xxx.yyy`. I want to "extract" `xxx.yyy` and `yyy` and give them names.

I can use [`regexp_matches`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) in postgres like so:

```sql
with const as (
  SELECT regexp_matches('xxx.yyy' ,'((.+\.).*)') as foo
)
select foo from const;
```

This returns:

```
{xxx.yyy,xxx.}
```

Now I know I can get the individual elements from the result by doing `(...)[1]` etc, but I want to know if there is a way of doing something like this:

```sql
with const as (
  SELECT regexp_matches('xxx.yyy' ,'((.+\.).*)') as (bar, baz)
)
select bar, baz from const;
```

the above syntax of course gives me an error. so I guess I want to know if there is a way to destructure/pattern match on an array in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like this

```
with const as (
  SELECT regexp_matches('xxx.yyy' ,'((.+\.).*)') as foo
)
select unnest(foo) from const;
```

or as named tuples

```
with const as (
  SELECT regexp_matches('xxx.yyy' ,'((.+\.).*)') as foo
)
select * from unnest((select foo from const), ARRAY['bar','baz']) as x(a,b);
```